# How do I change a stubborn start-here icon?

Tags: themes, icons, cache

I've been trying for a while now to change the **e** start-here icon that I have from the **Elementary** icon theme. I've replaced every start-here icon in the theme's folder, but I was told that Ubuntu also keeps a cache file, which may be the reason my changes do not take effect. How can I properly purge this "icon cache"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run `gtk-update-icon-cache` in the run dialogue or a terminal.

If that doesn't fix it, try changing the "distributor-logo" icon.

Comment: Thank you Roland! Although that did indeed do what I wanted, it didn't resolve my original problem with the icon. Now that I've replaced every icon in the folder, and run that command, I suppose this is now something I should take up with the creator.

Comment: @Alan: What menu are you using? Cardapio, Mint-Menu, or the standard menu? (Or something else?) It could be possible that the program using that icon is getting it from somewhere else.

Comment: I use the standard gnome menu, single icon. Although I am trying to switch to using AWN soon, with the YAMA (yet another menu applet) applet.

Comment: I have also changed all of the distributor-logo icons. This one is tough to track down.